# OSGi (felix) ignores OSGI-INF

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, osgi, apache-felix

I start felix framework myself. Everything is ok. But when I started with declarative services I see that felix ignores  OSGI-INF/temp.xml. In manifest I added via maven

```
Service-Component: OSGI-INF/temp.xml
```

Even when I write wrong classes and interfaces in temp.xml I get no errors. Where is mistake or maybe I must enable something?

Comment: Did you add/start the blueprint extender bundles to your run time environment?

Comment: @Martin Baumgartner I don't understand what you mean. Can you explain?

Comment: @Martin Baumgartner I found in internet. No, I didn't add/start blueprint bundle.

Comment: Sorry, i was missunderstanding your question. As far as i understand you want to use felix with SCR. Do you have the SCR Bundles inside your runtime? I've never used SCR, but as far as i understand you have to add some "stuff" (SCR Bundle which contains an activator) to your runtime. Please add some information how you start felix and which jars are deployed to the container.

Comment: @Martin Baumgartner I answered below, see, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An OSGi framework does not process Service-Component header. That is processed by a Declarative Services implementation like Apache Felix SCR. Do you have that installed and started?

Comment: Thank you, guys for you help. I didn't use any scr. Now I downloaded, install and start 1)org.apache.felix.scr-1.8.2.jar 2)org.apache.felix.scr.ds-annotations-1.2.4.jar. In this order, first I install all (apache and my bundles), after that I start 1,after 2 and at last my bundle. The problem is the same - it doesn't read temp.xml

Comment: Thank you for your help. So the right answer was in using felix scr and how to use it is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12660778/3505403

Comment: Maybe it's not very good of me to ask you for a help again :) but I think you have very good knowledge of OSGI. If you have time, could you look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22878449/how-to-bootstrap-weld-osgi-version-2-in-se-application